# Xamarin.Cognitive.Face API connecting problems

Tags: apache, api, xamarin.android, nuget-package, azure-cognitive-services

I tried to use this Nuget package, but I can't connect to the API. I got an error

> " Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class
>   java.lang.Class:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost;"

so I can't use any of the FaceClient functions- they're all return null.
I use Xamarin Android

Answer (score 0):

I added the line `<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />` at the `<applicaion>` tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file so it solved this problem.

Comment: Please do not forget to  mark your reply as answer(click ✔ at left and top your answer)， it will help others who have similar issue.